# Laravel middleware with parameter

Tags: laravel-8

I write middleare to decide permission. But giving error.

**Route page**

```
Route::middleware([Permission::class])->group(function($id){
});
```

**middleware**

```
 public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next,$id)
   {
         $id = $request->id; //$id is returning null                       
    
    }
```

**Giving this eror**
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Middleware\Permission::handle(), 2 passed in /home/saide/Desktop/saide-backoffice/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php on line 167 and exactly 3 expected

Answer (score 0):

I think when you called Middleware you used a square bracket, you have used an array for submitting the parameter to the middleware, use the below code

```
Route::middleware([Permission::class])->group(function($id){
});
```

For submitting multiple parameters through middleware use this code:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    //
})->middleware(['first', 'second']);
```

For passing single middleware use this:

```
Route::get('/profile', function () {
    //
})->middleware('auth');
```

Information Source: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the middleware is expecting a parameter and you aren't supplying it.

If you want your middleware to have an additional parameter `$id`, then route should be like this:

```php
Route::middleware([Permission::class.':id_value_goes_here'])->group(function () {
});
```

If you need the ID to be a dynamic parameter based on a route parameter (e.g. `Route::get('/posts/$id', ...)`) or something passed to the request, then you should omit the extra parameter from the middleware `handle()`'s method signature:

```php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $id = $request->id; // $id will now get correctly set
}
```